# Unique contraint violation whien trying to delete and add a row using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a project which which has hibernate classes mapped to the underlying tables. There is table which has a composite key.I am deleting the unique row and adding the same row in my hibernate object. Both these objects are part of another object which I am persisting into db. The program throws "UNIQUE CONSTRAINT VIOLATION" error which is presume is because insert is happening before delete operation. Is there way to resolve this using some setting in hibernate or should I have the necessary logic [outside hibernate object manipulation] in place to ensure this does not happen.

Comment: Please specify your mapping and entities and perhaps your tabledefinitions, as these things may lead to errors like this...

Answer (score 3):

You shall ensure that object deletion is flushed to database before you attempt to 
create another object with the same key.   But in your case it would be better to just replace
data inside of object to be remover with new one.  From hibernate point of view,  same PC means same object.

Answer (score 2):

When I have used Hibernate in the past, 90% of the time it makes no difference what order you call the insert or delete statement, or even the commit. In most cases, it matters where the session actually closes the Transaction unless you are managing your transaction yourself.

But one great thing about hibernate is that you shouldn't be removing a row that has the same key, you should just update its object instance with the relevant data and persist the update instance. Hibernate will take care of the rest...